# How to retrieve unique (removing duplicate) results from json response using andorid

Tags: android, json

I need to retrieve data from json webservice, I have read all data's in the json. but i need to store unique value from json.

Is it possible to fetch unique value from json?

following is my JSON data.

{"success":1,"data":[
{"unit_no":1,"unit_name":"Introduction","unitpointno":"1.1","unitpointname":"aa"},{"unit_no":1,"unit_name":"Introduction","unitpointno":"1.2","unitpointname":"bb"},{"unit_no":1,"unit_name":"Introduction","unitpointno":"1.3","unitpointname":"cc"},{"unit_no":2,"unit_name":"Laws","unitpointno":"2.1","unitpointname":"ww"},{"unit_no":2,"unit_name":"Laws","unitpointno":"2.2","unitpointname":"www"},{"unit_no":2,"unit_name":"Laws","unitpointno":"2.3","unitpointname":"wwww"},{"unit_no":2,"unit_name":"Laws","unitpointno":"2.4","unitpointname":"wwww"}]}

But, I want following ouput (Just remove the duplicate values i.e. Introduction and Laws)

```
1 Introduction
  1.1 aa
  1.2 bb
  1.3 cc
2 Laws
  2.1 ww
  2.2 www
  2.3 wwww
  2.4 wwww

private void viewunitandpointname()
{
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, EndPoints.SYLLABUS_VIEW_UNIT_AND_POINT, new Response.Listener<String>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response)
        {
            try {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray jsonArray = obj.getJSONArray("data");
                pdfList.clear();





                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
                {
                    //Declaring a json object corresponding to every pdf object in our json array
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    SyallbusList tlist = new SyallbusList();

                    String unit_no = jsonObject.getString("unit_no");
                    String unit_name = jsonObject.getString("unit_name");
                    String unit_point_no = jsonObject.getString("unitpointno");
                    String unit_point_name = jsonObject.getString("unitpointname");
                    String classname = jsonObject.getString("classname");
                    String subjname = jsonObject.getString("subjname");
                    String acyearname = jsonObject.getString("acyearname");

                    tlist.setUnitno(unit_no);
                    tlist.setUnitName(unit_name);
                    tlist.setpointno(unit_point_no);
                    tlist.setpointname(unit_point_name);
                    tlist.setClasname(classname);
                    tlist.setsubjectname(subjname);
                    tlist.setacyear(acyearname);

                    pdfList.add(tlist);


                }
                pdfAdapter=new SyllabusCompleListAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.syllabus_row,pdfList);
                listView.setAdapter(pdfAdapter);
                pdfAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
                {
                    // error
                    //Log.d("Error.Response", error.toString());
                }
            }

    ) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams()
        {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("acyear_id",academicyaerId);
            params.put("subj_id", subject_id);


            return params;
        }

    };

    RequestQueue request = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
    request.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your JSON output to return only unique value.

Use like this:

```
{
"success": 1,
"data": [{
            "unit_no": 1,
            "unit_name": "Introduction",
            "unit_point": [{

                "unitpointno": "1.1",
                "unitpointname": "aa"
            }, {

                "unitpointno": "1.2",
                "unitpointname": "bb"
            }, {

                "unitpointno": "1.3",
                "unitpointname": "cc"
            }]
        },
        {
            "unit_no": 2,
            "unit_name": "Laws",
            "unit_point ": [{

                    "unitpointno": "2.1",
                    "unitpointname": "ww"
                },
                {
                    "unitpointno": "2.2",
                    "unitpointname": "www"
                },
                {
                    "unitpointno": "2.3",
                    "unitpointname": "wwww"
                },
                {
                    "unitpointno": "2.4",
                    "unitpointname": "wwww"
                }]
        }]
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know but how Programatically  I do this. I have written above program, what changes i should do to get output.

Comment: It depends on how you process your data in your back end api.

Comment: I just given a PHP code were 1) unitno,unitname,pointno and pointname extracted from the table  by executing the query 2) Binding results to the query 3) traversing through all the result 4) displaying the result in json format

Comment: While traversing don't return the result directly, process the result and create json according to your condition.

Comment: I never did this before, Please suggest something more
 while($stmt->fetch())
 {
 $temp = array();
 
 $temp['unit_no'] = $unit_no; 
 $temp['unit_name'] = $unit_name; 
 $temp['unitpointno'] = $unit_point_no; 
 $temp['unitpointname'] = $unit_point_name; 
 $temp['classname'] = $class_name; 
 $temp['subjname'] = $subj_name; 
 $temp['acyearname'] = $acyear; 
 
 array_push($products, $temp);
 }

Answer (score 0):

```
Finally I got the solution, I simply did the following code...

if(pid==0 && i==0) 
{  
    pid=Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.getString("unit_no"));
    tlist.setUnitno(unit_no);
    tlist.setUnitName(unit_name);

}   
else  
{  
    nid=Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.getString("unit_no"));
    if(pid==nid) 
    {
         tlist.setUnitno("");
         tlist.setUnitName("");

    }
    else
    {
         tlist.setUnitno(unit_no);
         tlist.setUnitName(unit_name);
         pid=Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.getString("unit_no"));

     }
 }
```